# SwiftUI alignmentGuides inside background

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to change the anchor point of the red line without affecting the whole layout.
So instead of having its horizontal anchor point .leading i want to be .center. So the center of the red line aligns with the leading of the black line.

```
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Rectangle().fill(Color.Stock.gray).frame(height: 4)
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.red).frame(width: 40, height: 8)
                            .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.leading) { dim in
                                dim[HorizontalAlignment.center]
                            }
                },alignment: .leading)


    }.padding(.horizontal, 32)
```

**Result:**

[image]

It want like this (Instead of adding it as a background i added to the VStack, but this modifies my layout to the right):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated: Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Simplified, no hardcode - only alignments:

```
FirstView()
    .background(
        SecondView()
            .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.leading) { dim in
                dim[HorizontalAlignment.center]
            }
            .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.bottom) { dim in
                dim[VerticalAlignment.top]
            }
        ,alignment: .bottomLeading)
```

[Test code is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestAlignmentGuideReplacement.swift)

#### Original

Here is a demo of possible solution (with substituted color). Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

[image]

```
struct DemoView: View {
    private let height = CGFloat(4)
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Rectangle().fill(Color.gray).frame(height: height)
                .background(
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Rectangle().fill(Color.red).frame(width: 40, height: 8)
                            .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.leading) { dim in
                                dim[HorizontalAlignment.center]
                            }
                            .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center) { dim in
                                dim[VerticalAlignment.top] - height / 2
                            }
                    },alignment: .leading)
            
            
        }.padding(.horizontal, 32)
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for the response! I see comparing to yours that the problem with mines is the GeometryReader, if I remove it then it just works, can you explain me why? I need the geometry reader to read the width value, I forgot this part on the question sorry.